# How to extract group pattern from re pattern?

Tags: python

I have simple python code:

```
import re


regex=re.compile('some_regex(regex_in_first_group)other_regex')
```

Is there a way of extracting from such regular expression only expression that is in first group?

so in this situation I would like to obtain:

```
group_regex='regex_in_first_group'
```

Comment: Are you asking about extracting the **pattern** of the group match, or what was actually matched? I'm asking because you code does not contain an actual regex search.

Comment: Kindly give some sample example what will be your input and what is an expected output?

Comment: Have you checked out the docs? https://docs.python.org/3/howto/regex.html#grouping

Comment: I want to have regex from regex lets call it subregex. So if i have regular expression like: '^requests==(\d+\.\d+\.\d+)' I would like to have in output only this part of regex which is in first group in this situation '\d+\.\d+\.\d+' I do not want to match it now.

Answer (score 0):

Yes - use match objects. See https://docs.python.org/3.8/library/re.html#match-objects and especially the description of `Match.group()`.